# Are these uses of 'the press' metaphorical?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source: The Legal Analyst, Ward Farnsworth

> p 178: The result is a kind of slippery
>   slope.
>   [An indent ought to be here.] A different sort of slope, but related enough to consider here, occurs
>   when distinctions [between the first case and the later, scarier one] could
>   be drawn, both in principle and in practice, but they are too weak to
>   withstand the **press** of the policy preferences held by whoever is making
>   the later decisions.
>
> p 241: Meanwhile employees who get
>   fired may want to believe they have good claims, since that provides a
>   reason for their misfortunes unconnected with the quality of their work.
>   The decision in the case usually will depend on the employer’s motives,
>   and there often is no way to settle this objectively—no “smoking gun”
>   document where the motives are spelled out. It is a question of whose
>   protests to believe, how to interpret evaluations of the plaintiff’s work,
>   and what inferences to draw from remarks the defendant may have made.
>   The strength of these signals is liable to be too weak to withstand the **press**
>   of wishful thinking by either party.

Would someone please identify the matching [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/press)? I tried to guess but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of "too weak to withstand the press of" the word press means a consistent application of pressure or force in a particular direction. For example, "The audience surged forward to try to get closer to the stage and the barricades could not withstand the press of the crowd."

A related phrase is "[full-court press](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/full-court%20press)" which is a more aggressive form of the same concept. For example, "The supporters of the policy launched a full-court press in the media to attempt to change public opinion."